# python: loop a list of list and assign value inside the loop

Tags: python

I have the following code, why the first one doesn't change `alist` while the second changes it?

```
alist = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
for item in alist:
    item = 1
print(alist)

alist = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
for item in alist:
    item = item.append(10)
print(alist)
```

Comment: First change if used like this : `for item in alist : alist[alist.index(item)]= 1` So `item` is local variable in a loop, do nothing outside.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a somewhat unintuitive behavor of variables. It happens because, in Python, variables are always references to values.

## Boxes and tags

In some languages, we tend to think about variables as "boxes" where we put values; in Python, however, they are references, and behave more like tags or "nicknames" to values. So, when you attribute 1 to `item`, you are changing only the variable reference, not the list it is pointing to.

A graphic representation can help. The image below represents the list created by `alist = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]`

[image: A list with three sublists]

Given that, let's see what happens when we execute your first loop.

## The first loop

When you execute `for item in alist`, you are asking the interpreter to take each value from the list, one per time, put it on the variable `item` and do some operation in it. In the first operation, for example, we have this new schema:

[image: Now a variable points to a sublist]

Note that we do not copy the sublist to `item`; instead, we *point* to it through `item`. Then, we execute `item = 1` — but what does it mean? It mean that we are making `item` point to the value `1`, instead of pointing to the sublist:

[image: item points to other value now]

Note that the old reference is lost (it is the red arrow) and now we have a new. But we just changed a variable pointing to a list — we did not alter the list itself.

Then, we enter to the second iteration of the loop, and now `item` points to the second sublist:

[image: item pointing to the second sublist]

When we execute `item = 1`, again, we just make the variable point to aonther value, without changing the list:

[image]

Now, what happens when we execute the second loop?

## The second loop

The second loop starts as the first one: we make `item` refer to the first sublist:

[image: Now a variable points to a sublist]

The first difference, however, is that we call `item.append()`. `append()` is a *method*, so it can change the value of the object it is calling. As we use to say, we are sending a *message* to the object pointed by `item` to append the value 10. In this case, the operation is *not* being made in the variable `item`, but directly in the object it refers! So here is the result of calling `item.append()`:

[image: A list has grown]

However, we do not only append a value to the list! We also assign the value returned by `item.append()`. This will sever the `item` reference to the sublist, but here is a catch: `append()` returns `None`.

[image]

## The `None` value

`None` is a value that represents, basically, the unavailability of a relevant value. When a function returns `None`, it is saying, most of the time, "I have nothing relevant to give you back." `append()` does change its list directly, so there is nothing it needs to return.

It is important because you probably believed `item` would point to the appended list `[1, 2, 10]`, right? No, now it points to `None`. So, you would expect the code below...

```
alist = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
for item in alist:
    item = item.append(10)
    print(item)
```

To print something like this:

```
[1, 2, 10]
[3, 4, 10]
[5, 6, 10]
```

But this *does not* happen. *This* is what happens:

```
>>> alist = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
>>> for item in alist:
...     item = item.append(10)
...     print(item)
...
None
None
None
```

Yet, as we commented, the `append()` method changed the lists themselves. So, while the `item` variable was useless after the assignment, the final list is modified!

```
>>> print alist
[[1, 2, 10], [3, 4, 10], [5, 6, 10]]
```

If you want to use the appended list inside the loop, just do not assign the method returned value to `item`. Do this:

```
>>> alist = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
>>> for item in alist:
...     item.append(10)
...     print item
... 
[1, 2, 10]
[3, 4, 10]
[5, 6, 10]
```

This works because `item` will still point to the list.

## Conclusion

References are somewhat complex to understand at first, let alone master. Yet, they are really powerful and can be learned if you follow examples etc. Your example is a bit complicated because there is more happening here.

The [Python Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/) can help you understand what is going on, because it executes each step graphically. [Check your own code running there!](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=alist%20%3D%20%5B%5B1,2%5D,%20%5B3,4%5D,%20%5B5,6%5D%5D%0Afor%20item%20in%20alist%3A%0A%20%20%20%20item%20%3D%201%0Aprint(alist%29%0A%0Aalist%20%3D%20%5B%5B1,2%5D,%20%5B3,4%5D,%20%5B5,6%5D%5D%0Afor%20item%20in%20alist%3A%0A%20%20%20%20item%20%3D%20item.append(10%29%0Aprint(alist%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Answer (score 4):

In the first example `item` is bound to each element in list `alist`, and then `item` is *rebound* to the integer `1`. This does not change the element of the list - it merely *rebinds* the name `item` to the `int` object `1`.

In the second example the list element (itself a list) is mutated by `append()`. `item` is still bound to the sub-list so `item.append()` mutates the sub-list.

Answer (score 2):

Are you forgetting that `list.append()` does not return the list itself but actually modifies the list in place?

`item = 1` does as expected. For the rest of the for-loop, item is now `1`, and not the list it originally was. It won't reassign what `item` is, that's not what for-loops do.

However, in your second loop, you're now assigning `item = None`, because the append function does not return anything but it appends the item to the list in place:

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 3]
>>> L.append(4)
>>> L
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Thus, your code is basically saying "go through each sublist in my main list and append `10` to it".

Answer (score 2):

The `=` operator does not make any change in the second code, using `.append` causes changes in `alist`. Use following line as the third line in the second code. You will see the same result:

```
item.append(10)
```

In the first code `item` point to another object by `item=1`, so `alist` does not change. In the second code you make change on `alist` by calling `append` method of it.

Answer (score 2):

It's pointer variable in python.

The first example:

```
for item in alist:
   item = 1
```

each item is pointing to each _item in alist but suddenly you change the item value, not the of the value of the _item in alist, as a result nothing change to alist

The second example:

```
for item in alist:
    item = item.append(10)
```

each item is pointing to each _item in alist and then you append something to the item sharing the same memory location of _item, as a result value of _item in alist are changed and alist is changed too.

Answer (score 1):

Referencing [the document](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement):

> The for-loop makes assignments to the variables(s) in the target list.
>   This overwrites all previous assignments to those variables including
>   those made in the suite of the for-loop:
>
> ```
> for i in range(10):
>     print(i)
>     i = 5             # this will not affect the for-loop
>                       # because i will be overwritten with the next
>                       # index in the range
> ```

So your second example is identical to:

```
alist = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
for item in alist:
    item.append(10)    # this statement modifies each item in alist
                       # , which is what item the variable "points to"
print(alist)
```

That is to say, `item` is a new variable **in every iteration**. As a result, assigning values to it in any specific iteration is pointless, because its value will be overridden by the reference to the next item in `alist` at the very beginning of the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
for item in alist:
```

You are actually creating a copy of each item in `liast` in the `item` variable, and you are *not* getting a reference to `item`.

However, `append` changes the list in-place and doesn't return a value, and that's why you're getting the values changed to `None` (due to the assignment - if you remove it you'll get the appending working fine).

Comment: `for each` block in python does not make any copy, i.e `item` points to each member of `alist` in every iteration.